# What do I declare message length as? int or char?

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to coding and would like to know how do I declare message length (mlen) and ciphertext (clen) length in my c++ code. However, I am not too sure what am I suppose to declare them as. (int? char? unsigned long long?) 
The formula that was given to me to include in my code is:

`*clen = mlen + CRYPTO_ABYTES`

Information that was given to me is:

It operates on a state of 320-bits with message blocks of 64 bits.

UPDATE: Sorry for the bad question, I realized I was given unsigned long long for the message length, it was written in a smaller font that I did not realized it.

Comment: The best advice is to talk to the person who gave you the formula.  Always review the requirements until both you and the customer have the same understanding.

Comment: You may find yourself wanting [Fixed Width Integers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: One issue is that the data type depends on the encryption algorithm.  For example, a simple XOR checksum can be implemented using an 8-bit integer.  A SHA-1 requires more bits.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no strict requirement regarding how big your type has to be, you should use the native C++ type designed to represent sizes:

**`std::size_t`**

The main advantages of `std::size_t` over types such as `unsigned int`, `unsigned short` etc is:

1. It is capable of holding the maximum possible size of any C++ type, including arrays (since it's defined as the result type of the `sizeof` operator).
2. As such, it's often optimized to your architecture (e.g. RAM address space).
3. It is typically used as the type to represent indices and lengths in `new[]`, `std::vector`, and large parts of the STL in general. As you are likely going to use such data structures and algorithms, you can avoid useless conversions between different types, making your code more readable, without compiler warnings.
4. The type `std::size_t` in your code tells you something about its semantics (indices and sizes; unsigned implied). Other integer types such as `unsigned int` can be used to represent *anything*.

For additional information, check out [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).

On the other hand, if you need to pack your data tightly (e.g. for network protocol), you should use the smallest possible type such as `std::uint16_t`, `std::uint32_t` etc.